# Arcmap 10.4 new north arrow?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts, arcgis-10.4, north-arrow

I update from ArcMap 10.3 to 10.4.

When I export a map, I always used the "normal" north arrow, i.e. the first arrow on the top-left in the image shown here:

[image]

After I update to ArcMap 10.4 is that now, when I select the first north arrow type, that in the preview still appears as the one I always used, something different pops up on the map. The new north arrow looks a lot like the central one on the figure I showed before.

Am I the only one with this problem? How can I go back to my previous north arrow (with just the "N" letter written on it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in arcmap 10.4, yet there is a work around.

First, add a north arrow (any north arrow you want). Then:

`Right click the arrow > Properties > Change Symbol... > Edit Symbol...`

In the new menu change the Subset to `Latin-1 Supplement` and set Unicode to `220`.

See image:

[image: Example]

Comment: Found, thank you a lot. Should we report the bug somehow to Esri? In case, how should we do it?

Comment: @TommasoSacco. We could, I actually can't find where should I report a bug in ESRI support website.